# PHPUnit test of a JSON returned from another file

Tags: php, json, phpunit

on my web-server I have a PHP file that performs a query to a database and then return a JSON that I use in my Android application.

**LoginUser.php**

```
require "conn.php";
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$json = file_get_contents('php://input', true);
$json = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$type = $json["type"];

$mail = $json['email'];
$pw= $json['password'];
$mysql_qry = "SELECT * FROM  utenti WHERE email like '$mail' and password like '$pw'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $res['Result'] = "true";
    $res['Status'] = "Login OK";
    //do other stuf...
}else{
    $res['Result'] = "false";
    $res['Status'] = "Login FAILED";
}

echo json_encode($res);
return json_encode($res);

?>
```

Now I have to write a unit test with PHPUnit for checking that the response is in the correct format. I've tried different things and now I have a thing like this:

**Test.php**

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class TestLogin extends TestCase{

    public function testCorrectLogin(){

        $this->post(
            [mail => "prova@gmail.com", password=> "111"]
        )->seeStatusCode(200);

        include '/var/www/html/pizzino_php/loginU.php';
    }
}

?>
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You were 90% there, the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) states that return values in a file that is included (or required) will return a value as if it were a function.

> Also, it's possible to return values from included files. You can take
>   the value of the include call as you would for a normal function.

```php
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class TestLogin extends TestCase{

    public function testCorrectLogin(){

        $this->post(
            [mail => "prova@gmail.com", password=> "111"]
        )->seeStatusCode(200);

        $json = json_decode( include '/var/www/html/pizzino_php/loginU.php' );

        // Now do your checks on $json

    }
}

?>
```

If you want to prevent the echoed strings from appearing you can use `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()` before and after the include line.

Comment: It gaves me an error: `Error: Call to undefined method TestLogin::post()`. Seems that I have to make a function inside LoginUser..

Comment: PHPUnit is not an HTTP client. You will need to include one, such as Guzzle, in order to post to a URL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm really new to this kind of stuff.. I have the two php file on the same web server, so I only need to pass the JSON to the other file for testing